# Restringir el acceso de un usuario a una sola tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql

De esta forma le asigno los mismos permisos a todas las tablas de la base de datos prueba_bd al usuario juanucho, pero lo que yo quiero es que este usuario no tenga acceso a una tabla en particular.

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON prueba_bd.* to juanucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con:

```
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON prueba_bd.tabla_restringida TO juanucho@'%'
```

Comment: indica que esta sentencia la debe ejecutar despues de la que ha indicado el. ¿Aparte no falta el UPDATE?

Comment: Sí, debe ser ejecutada después de la sentencia que indicó.
Quedaría de la siguiente manera:
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON prueba_bd.tabla_restringida TO juanucho@'%'

Comment: Me da error. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO juanucho@'%'' at line 1

Comment: REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON prueba_bd.tabla_restringida TO juanucho 
También puedes probar agregandole comillas a juanucho y colocando el @'%'

Comment: El problema es que revoke_partial está desabilitado por defecto en mysql, ahora estoy intentando habilitarlo.